# put vectors into a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, data-structures

My map: map  `<string, vector<vector<string> > >.`
The map key is the user name. 
`vector<vector<string> > >` is used to stored all messages an user received.
`vector<string>` is used to store each message which has subject, data, etc.

Now I want to add `vector<vector<string> > >` into my map.
My code :

```
vector<vector<string> > messageList;
vector<string> eachMessage;
    if(messageMap.find(name)==messageMap.end()) //to see if an user has already been put into the map
{
    messageMap.insert( pair<string, vector<vector<string> > >(name,messageList)); // create a new map

    eachMessage.push_back(subject); // add information
    eachMessage.push_back(totalMessage);
    messageList.push_back(eachMessage);// put each message into the messageList
}
else 
{
    eachMessage.push_back(subject);
    eachMessage.push_back(totalMessage);
    messageMap.find(name)->second.push_back(eachMessage);
}
```

However, this code can not correctly put message information for each user. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: "However, this code can not correctly put message information for each user." -> Which means what? The program doesn't compile? It compiles but crashes? It runs but gives corrupt output?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This code can not put right messageList into each user.

Comment: I suggest you use map's `operator[]` which will automatically create the entry if it doesn't exist. `auto& entry = messageMap[name];` now you can push back directly into the entry instead of making many copies. It will also only search the map once, whereas you do 2 lookups per operation.

Comment: You might find it convenient to make typedefs for types such as vector<string>.

Comment: When you insert into the vector it makes a copy. So you are adding the data to a different vector to the one that gets inserted.

Comment: @NeilKirk That is unsafe, and vulnerable to stack overflow, if the programmer doesn't know exactly what they are doing. Better to use `at()`, `push_back`

Comment: @self `at` will throw an exception if the entry does not exist. I have no idea why you think `operator[]` is unsafe or could cause a stack overflow.

Comment: `my_vector[LONG_MAX + 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `[]` operator it will automatically create a new entry if it doesn't already exist meaning you don't need your big `if()`. You can reduce your code to this:

```
messageMap[name].push_back(vector<string>()); // new message
messageMap[name].back().push_back(subject); // add entries to the message
messageMap[name].back().push_back(totalMessage);
```

Remember `messageMap[name]` will create a new `vector<vector<string> >` if one doesn't already exist for that `name` **or** re-use the one that is already there.

The `.emplace_back()` adds a new `vector<string>` to the back of that vector.

The `.back()` access the `vector<string>` that you just made at the back.

**Note:** As @NeilKirk says in the comments you can be more efficient by taking a reference to the map element so it doesn't need to be looked up each time:

```
auto& messageList = messageMap[name]; // retrieve or create message list
messageList.push_back(vector<string>()); // new message
messageList.back().push_back(subject); // add entries to the message
messageList.back().push_back(totalMessage);
```

Comment: You should use `auto& entry = messageMap[name];` to avoid searching the map several times.

Comment: Thank you. @Galik  When I run your code, it gives the error. "no member named 'emplace_back' in       'std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > > > >'

Comment: @user3709122 Your compiler is probably missing C++11 support. Try `entry.resize(entry.size()+1);` where entry is a reference to the value in the map.

Comment: Thank you. May you teach me exactly how I should change my code to?

Comment: @NeilKirk I've added your suggestion as an alternative, more efficient way. I was trying to keep it simple but, this is never going to be a simple data structure for beginners.

Comment: @user3709122 I changed it to work with pre-C++11 code. Instead of `emplace_back` I put `.push_back(vector<string>());`

Comment: @Galik Thank you very much.